# How to space out columns for site content columns in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, site-column, site-contents

How do we space out columns on the **site content page** within a SharePoint Online site?

The columns appear to be locked in width as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I want the Name column to be wider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any out of the box way to control the listing & columns on site contents page.

Comment: It would be nice if that left quick links side bar could collapse to icons so that the page columns could increase in width just a little more.  Perhaps a SharePoint Online v2  feature...